# Running a Trimmed Self-Contained Single Executable using .NetCore 3.1-Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, powershell-7.0

I am invoking PowerShell script in a Console application which has .Net Core 3.1 as target framework. When I run the solution in debug mode,the PowerShell command is working fine but when I run the Trimmed Self-Contained Single Executable  I am getting below error:

> There is exceptionSystem.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot
> find the file specified. File name:
> 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() at
> System.Reflection.Assembly.get_ExportedTypes() at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.GetAssemblyTypes(Assembly
> assembly, String name) at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzeModuleAssemblyWithReflection(Assembly
> assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo
> moduleInfo, String helpFile, Dictionary2& cmdlets, Dictionary2&
> aliases, Dictionary2& providers) at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzePSSnapInAssembly(Assembly
> assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo
> moduleInfo, Dictionary2& cmdlets, Dictionary2& aliases, Dictionary2&
> providers, String& helpFile) at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.ImportPSSnapIn(PSSnapInInfo
> psSnapInInfo, PSSnapInException& warning) at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
> at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(PSHost
> host) at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
> at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace
> rsToUse, Boolean isSync) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection1
> input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection1
> input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input,
> PSInvocationSettings settings) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()

I tried adding **Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure** package through Nuget but still there is same issue. Interesting that is looking for the 1.0.0.0 version while I have the 2.0.0.0 which is installed in my project.
If anyone has suggestions on how to proceed it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you leave the old reference in place? You should *remove* the original reference you added by hand and ensure only the NuGet package is used

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kanavos,I have not added any reference manually but have installed them through Nuget package.I am getting mentioned error when I am running the trimmed self-contained executable.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this issue or is it something to do with powershell compatibility with .netcore 3.0?